# Help in this content extraction + beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a site which is in this format

```
<div id=storytextp class=storytextp align=center style='padding:10px;'> 
<div id=storytext class=storytext> 
<div class='a2a_kit a2a_default_style' style='float:right;margin-left:10px;border:none;'> 
..... extra stuff
</div>  **Main Content**
</div>
</div>
```

Note that the MainContent can contain other tags but i want the entire content like string

So what i did was this

```
_divTag = data.find( "div" , id = "storytext" )
innerdiv = _divTag.find( "div" ) # find the first div tag
innerdiv.contents[0].replaceWith("") # replace with null
```

thus the _divTag will have only the main  content but this does not work. Can anybody tell what mistake i am making and how should i extract the main content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `_divTag.contents[2]`.

Your formatting was maybe misleading you - this text does not belong to the innermost div tag (as `innerdiv.text`, `innerdiv.contents` or `innerdiv.findChildren()` will show you).

It makes things clearer if you indent your original XML:

```
<div id=storytextp class=storytextp align=center style='padding:10px;'> 
  <div id=storytext class=storytext> 
    <div class='a2a_kit a2a_default_style' style='float:right;margin-left:10px;border:none;'> 
      ..... extra stuff
    </div>  **Main Content**
  </div>
</div>
```

(PS: I'm not clear what the intent of your `innerdiv.contents[0].replaceWith("")` was? To squelch the attributes? newlines? Anyway, the BS philosophy is not to edit the parse-tree, but simply to ignore the 99.9% that you don't care about. BS Documentation is [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)).

Comment: Hey but it happens that my main content is some thing like more tags <p> ....<\p> .. When i do what you have said it just prints the first paragraph tag in the main content and the rest after that do not come. What i was trying to do was to replace the first inner div tag by null string so that everything after this could be called by contents[0]

Comment: Can you edit your example text to show where the multiple lines go? It's probably `_divTag.contents[2:]`